# How can I order record with include models count?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, count, include, sequelize.js

I am new in postress and try to implement postress with nodejs using sequelize, I am stuff in one query actually I need to sort data using include models count.

```
user = sequelize.define("users",
{
 ....different Field
});

const order = sequelize.define("orders",
{
.... different field,
 sellerId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  field: "sellerId",
  allowNull: false
},
});

order.belongsTo(user, { as: "seller", foreignKey: "sellerId" });
user.hasMany(order, { foreignKey: "sellerId" });
```

now I need for fetch user and users order and then sort user by there order count I tried with following

```
let result = await user.findAndCountAll({
    where: condition,
    attributes: [
       'users.*',
       [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('orders.id')), 'orders']
    ],
    include: [
    {
        model: order,
        attributes: [],
        required: false,
    },
    {
        other model
    }
    ],
    order: [
        ["orders", "DESC"]
    ],
    distinct: true,
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
});
```

But I am facing an error like: (node:20820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders".

Anyone knows the reason or any alternative for archive my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sequelize.literal maybe?